# How would a switch statement look like which has to express a complex condition that contains both logical operators (|| and &&)?

Tags: javascript, nested, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I have to build a condition based on *one* or *two* values.

```
const getLabel = (type?: string, typeXy?: string) => {
  let label;

  switch (type || typeXy) {
    case 'Value A':
      label = 'Label A';
      break;
    case 'Value B':
      label = 'Label B';
      break;
    case 'Value C':
    case 'Value X':
      label = 'Label C + X';
      break;
    case 'Value Y':
      label = 'Label C + Y';
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return label;
};
```

I need a dubbel case on two places. When I add `case 'Value C':` above `case 'Value Y':` I get:

> Duplicate case label.eslintno-duplicate-case

**1)** I add `// eslint-disable-next-line no-duplicate-case` but my code isn't working yet. Or is there a cleaner way anyway?

**2)** I can change my switch from the `or` to the `and`: `(type || typeXy)` but then the first case isn't working? How do I support both `or` and `and`?

Comment: When do you need logical OR (`||`) and when do you need logical AND (&&)? Can you explain what you want the code to do in English sentences/bullet points?

Comment: Expression `a || b` has a concrete meaning: "result in a value of `a`, unless it is falsy; if `a` is falsy, then result in the value of `b`"

Comment: For the third case, do you mean `type` contains "Value C"  *and* `typeXy` contains "Value X"?

Comment: For the first two cases (case 'Value A' and case 'Value B') I need the Or (`||`) because I need to pass `type` there. For case 'Value C' I need both `type` and `typeXy`. And the same for the one below which should return `'Label C + Y'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question you want to conditionally check if both arguments are passed and if so, use a logical AND comparison, otherwise if only one or the other is passed revert to a logical OR comparison.

Use an outer switch to branch on the logical AND/OR condition, and then use nested switches to evaluate the specific AND or OR combinations.

```js
const getLabel = (type /*?: string*/, typeXy /*?: string*/) => {
  switch (true) {
    case !!(type && typeXy):
      switch (type) {
        case "Value C": {
          let label = "Label C";
          switch (typeXy) {
            case "Value X":
              return label + " + X";
            case "Value Y":
              return label + " + Y";
          }
        }
      }
      break;

    case !!(type || typeXy):
      switch (type || typeXy) {
        case "Value A":
          return "Label A";
        case "Value B":
          return "Label B";
      }
  }
};

console.log(getLabel("Value A"));            // Label A
console.log(getLabel("Value B"));            // Label B
console.log(getLabel(undefined, "Value A")); // Label A
console.log(getLabel(undefined, "Value B")); // Label B
console.log(getLabel("Value C", "Value X")); // Label C + X
console.log(getLabel("Value C", "Value Y")); // Label C + Y
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! That works fine. However you get a lot of nested switch statements. Would a cleaner solution maybe with `if/else` statements in this case?

Comment: @meez ... there is nothing *"dirty"* with the above code. Thus there is nothing *"cleaner"*. Any syntax which supports complex logic (switch case, if else, ternary and boolean operators) in the end  will be nested in order to express the OP's needs. The only shortcut, which also might be easier to read and to maintain, could be a lookup based approach.

Comment: @Drew Reese can you explain why you use the double `!!` here? Just to understand.

Comment: @Peter Seliger what do you mean with the lookup based approach?

Comment: @meez I don't know about cleaner solution, but a `switch` statement is effectively "syntactic sugar" around a series of if-else-if statements. The double-bang (`!!`) is used to coerce the conditional expressions to a boolean value for the `switch` cases. Peter means a lookup map/object of each stringified combination of logical OR and AND of the arguments.

Comment: @meez ... a lookup is based on a key value structure, hence object entries. Thus one can try accessing an object's property value by its property name (key). In the OP's case one would create an object with all property names (and their related values) which possibly can be created from any combination of the function's provided string arguments. Thus a lookup based approach is pretty fast and, as I already have mentioned, might even be easier to read and to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an object literal as lookup table where one can precisely express with, which result for which case one does prefer ?..

```js
const getLabel = (type/*?: string*/, typeXy/*?: string*/) => {
  return ({

    'Value A': 'Label A',
    'Value B': 'Label B',
    'Value C': 'Label C',
    'Value X': 'Label X',
    'Value Y': 'Label Y',
    'Value CValue X': 'Label C + X',
    'Value XValue C': 'Label C + X',
    'Value CValue Y': 'Label C + Y',
    'Value YValue C': 'Label C + Y',

  })[(type ?? '') + (typeXy ?? '')];
};

console.log("getLabel('Value A') ...", getLabel('Value A'));

console.log("getLabel('Value B', null) ...", getLabel('Value B', null));
console.log("getLabel(null, 'Value C') ...", getLabel(null, 'Value C'));
console.log("getLabel(undefined, 'Value X') ...", getLabel(undefined, 'Value X'));

console.log("getLabel('Value Y') ...", getLabel('Value Y'));

console.log("getLabel('Value C', 'Value X') ...", getLabel('Value C', 'Value X'));
console.log("getLabel('Value X', 'Value C') ...", getLabel('Value X', 'Value C'));

console.log("getLabel('Value C', 'Value Y') ...", getLabel('Value C', 'Value Y'));
console.log("getLabel('Value Y', 'Value C') ...", getLabel('Value Y', 'Value C'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @meez ... Are there any questions regarding the above approach?